# Setting masterpage literal results in blank output

Tags: asp.net

Wondering if someone can help me out here. New to ASP.NET.

Trying to output the PageName in a masterpage.

Masterpage has a Literal in  which I am setting by accessing a property on the MasterPage "PageTitle".

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:Literal ID="litTitle" runat="server"/></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" />
</head>
```

The child page is like this:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="content">
<%
    MasterPage master  = Master as MasterPage;
    master.PageName = "Log in";
%>
</asp:Content>
```

And the property PageName is coded thusly:

```
    private string _pageName;
    public string PageName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _pageName; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            _pageName = value; 
            litTitle.Text = _pageName;
        } 
    }
```

I'm guessing this is because the page output has already been rendered, but as I say I don't know enough about ASP.NET. I guess I'm after something similar to PHPs ob_start().

Comment: You should accept one of these answers, or provide feedback if they were not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the page Title from the master page code-behind as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string title = this.MainContent.Page.Title;
}
```

Note you will need to give your placeholder a name in the .Master file.
If you want to retrieve the value other than the Title, do something like this:
string title = (MyPage)this.MainContent.Page).MyValue;

Answer (score -1):

You can find more about Master page and setting an property value in master page at below mentioned link.

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/asp.net-master-pages-tips-and-tricks/

I think here you can find your desire solution.

Comment: This is not answer....-> "You can find more about Master page on www.msdn.com, I think that you can find your answer there." Especial here, the user Jared did not know how to handle some thinks on master page, just by looking what you have give him you make it more confuze and nothing is about the real problem that he have, he try to set the title, but the title is a parameter of the page. So you have make 2 error on your answer, one you do not give an answer, second you didnt understand what he asking about and what he tries to do with.